# How to I create a preview for devise_intiable mailer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, devise-invitable

I hooked up [devise_invitable gem](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable)

And everything is working correctly in my dev environment. I can view the mailer html in the terminal, I can copy the URL with the token it sends. And when I put that in browser and go to that path it works perfectly.

I would however like to create a preview for this so I can preview the mailer as I get that part how I want it.

Here's what I've tried so far.

In test/mailers/previews

and my code is something like this:

```
class InviteAdminPreview < ActionMailer::Preview
  def invite
    InviteAdminMailer.invite(Admin.last)
  end
end
```

but this isn't really working because I don't know what the actual invite mailer is called. Because in app/mailers where I would have expected devise_invitable to place this mailer, there is nothing there.

So should I create my own mailer here called InviteAdminMailer? Or is there some other way to do it?

Also will i have to create this .invite method myself in this mailer so this preview will work?

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

```
  def invitation_instructions
    Devise::Mailer.invitation_instructions(User.all.sample, 'faketoken')
  end
```

Comment: This no longer works in newer version of devise/devise_invitable/

Answer (score 1):

First of all, to create a customized mail for `devise_invitable` usage, you can reference the article "Customizing for different Invite use cases (emails etc.)" https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable/wiki/Customizing-for-different-Invite-use-cases-(emails-etc.) from `devise_invitable` wiki.

According to `devise_invitable` source code ( https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable/blob/cf77519ca9d02c112d99fd176a8852272c1b8d99/lib/devise_invitable/models.rb#L210 ), it uses the mailer provided by devise, so there is no `devise_inviatble` mailer. If you want to preview devise mails, you can do something as below:

From: https://gist.github.com/ThawanFidelis/ac4a215b841619eae7d8

```
# config/enviroments/development.rb
config.action_mailer.preview_path = "#{Rails.root}/app/mailer_previews"


# app/mailer_previews/devise_mailer_preview.rb
class Devise::MailerPreview < ActionMailer::Preview
  def confirmation_instructions
    Devise::Mailer.confirmation_instructions(User.first, {})
  end

  def unlock_instructions
    Devise::Mailer.unlock_instructions(User.first, "faketoken")
  end

  def reset_password_instructions
    Devise::Mailer.reset_password_instructions(User.first, "faketoken")
  end
end
```

Comment: This worked for me when changing the name of the class to DeviseMailerPreview